# How to use eslint plugin modules located in parent directory?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, eslint, package.json, monorepo

I have some services organized into a monorepo in such a fashion:

`repo_root/
├── services/
│   ├── service_one/
│   ├── service_two/
│   └── service_three/
├── package.json
├── node_modules
├── .eslintrc`

Additionally, each individual service has its own `package.json` and `node_modules`. I would like to use the eslint configuration stored in the `repo_root` directory to lint individual services. My problem is that when I try to run something like

`eslint services/service_one`

for example, it fails to find the eslint plugin modules that are required by `.eslintrc` and installed in the `node_modules` directory of `repo_root`.

I'd like to avoid redundantly requiring these plugin modules in every service. Is there anyway to configure eslint to intelligently find the modules even though they are in the parent directory of the services themselves?

Comment: based on what you described, it should work since evything looks right. Can you share the exact error and you u sure the plugin is installed.. also share your .eslintrc content

Comment: best case would be if you can share the project or setup a reproducible  case on github n share the link here...

Comment: You're right, see my answer below. I'll be sure to post some example code next time as well. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering, my problem was I was running the command using a globally installed eslint, which in turn looked for global modules. After changing it to run a local version of eslint, everything worked fine!